# Woocommerce product having specific tag should be first in list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product, listings

I want to display the products first in the list having a specific tag and others which are not having that tag should come after those products which are having that specific tag

Comment: Please post the code snippet to give a starting point.

Comment: I have not created any code @KiranManiya